# Unlock with fingerprint instead of PIN after Device reboot or Device Locked by admin

Tags: root-access, security, lineageos, fingerprint, resurrection-remix-os

Android has a security feature that requires the user to input PIN/Pattern/Password if the device was locked by an app using the [Device Administrator](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) permission or when the device is restarted.

Recently though, I've started using custom ROMs like [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org) and [Resurrection Remix](http://www.resurrectionremix.com/). I happened to notice something interesting in Resurrection Remix: that it allows you to use fingerprint even after an admin device lock or device restart. Take a look at the screen capture below.

[image: IMG:]

You'll find this setting typically under `Settings > Customizations > Interfaces > Fingerprint settings`.

Now, with that option enabled, it allows me to unlock device with fingerprint auth. regardless of the method with which the device was locked before.

I've since switched to LineageOS for reasons but I kind of want this feature and am looking for help. I've also looked a bit into the [Resurrection Remix Sources](https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix/Resurrection_packages_apps_Settings) but was unable to find anything helpful.

Perhaps, maybe, is there a `build.prop` hack/tweak/option I could use to get said feature in LineageOS too?

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Note: In before someone points out, I understand this option, if enabled, can seriously downplay device security but I kind of want to learn about why it works how it works. I do not necessarily plan to enable this but learning is always interesting. I also happen to understand code a bit, please feel free to use code instances (I was thinking about `Android Keystore` auth code) to make things more clearer should need be.

Comment: This is kinda bordering on being off topic. Anyway, to tweaks to achieve your goal. I do not want to say definitively No because someone more familiar with the tweaking the system knows. Getting this setting to favorite rom heads to off topic per development. I believe the flow is from one branch `cherry pick/resolve conflicts/merge` to another branch. Code sources: https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix/Resurrection_packages_apps_Settings/commit/e5a04e73474010497939e6198db78b78ed512519
https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix/android_frameworks_base/commit/1ec5bc4ceb939ae06878ff2063ccf4aebcf4053f

Comment: Agreed with "bordering on being off topic" part but I couldn't think of any place better. Maybe you can point me to places where more help can be expected. Anyway, the commit link that you've given was helpful and sort of solves the problem. I'm going to study that code and see if I come up with something. Thanks @BoLawson